# Rasterio installation problem

Tags: mapbox, rasterio

I've installed `rasterio` using `pip`, I want to run command line `rio`, but I have this traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rio", line 7, in <module>
    from rio.manage import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rio/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .app import create_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rio/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from rio.setup import configure_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rio/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .core import db
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rio/core.py", line 14, in <module>
    from flask_user import UserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_user/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin as LoginUserMixin, make_secure_token
ImportError: cannot import name make_secure_token
```

What does it mean?

Comment: You have a problem because rasterio/rio don't need flask (see [/requirements.txt](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/requirements.txt))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you that it can't import the function `make_secure_token` from the `flask` package. If you don't already have `flask` installed, use `pip install flask` and the issue should be resolved.

I found this note on it:

https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/issues/143

Looks like it was a bug in Flask that has since been fixed -- consider upgrading to v0.6.9 +

Comment: Unfortunately, it's already there installed.

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: This is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `from rio.manage import main` in the traceback tells me that your /usr/local/bin/rio isn't from Rasterio at all. That's your problem. If you ran `pip install rio` you probably installed https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rio. If you want Rasterio, you need to run `pip install rasterio`.